# Django html email

Tags: django

I am working a project where need to send html email . A url need to insert the html content, like

```
<p><a href="http://dealerfunnel.com/passwordchange">Password Change Link</a></p>
```

My domain name , `dealerfunnel.com`. If I put any valid url except http://dealerfunnel.com then email is sending. Like If I put

`google.com`

then email is sending. But when I put `dealerfunnel.com` , email is not sending and do not get any error.

Please review my code:

```
from dealerfunnel.funnel.view.base import *
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
import sys

class debug():
    def sendmail(self,request):
        message = get_template('mail/forgot.html').render(Context({"name":"Khalid Hossain"}))   
       try:
            msg = EmailMessage('Password Change',message, to=['khalidrashed@gmail.com'], from_email='support@domainname')
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()
            return HttpResponse(message)
        except :
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            return HttpResponse(e)
```

Comment: Why not use the django [password reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) forms?

Comment: Show your settings.py

Comment: and your urls, you shouldn't be hard coding a page link, you should be using the `url` template tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is what u can do

```
def send_notification_email(template, **kwargs):
    subject = "Your subject here"
    context = Your_Context
    email = Your_Email
    body = render_to_string(template, {'context':context})
    return send_mail(subject, body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email], fail_silently=True)
```

This is if your are calling this function from your view..
If not then you can use template explicitely in send_mail method.

Now in your template you cann write anything you want and the mail should be send